# How to keep track of geofences when app is not running

Tags: android, android-service, android-broadcast, android-geofence

I am using geofence service in my app and using exactly the same sample as given in the google documentation.
Doing some research i found that the Intent service is killed when the app is killed. I want to receive the geofence notifications even when the app is not running. How can i do that.?

I have looked for the examples using broadcast receivers but they are old and use classes which are deprecated.